# default argument : invalid use of 'this' outside of a non-static member function

Tags: c++, arguments, default

I try to have a default parameter in my functions but the compiler says there is an error :

```
invalid use of 'this' outside of a non-static member function
```

How can I fix this ?

**Edit :** @RSahu, here is the two overloaded functions, can you explain me how I can manage the problem because apparently I didn't understand how to fix it.

Game.hpp :

```
class Game {
 private :
  int** board;

  vector<pair <int, int> > listPiecesPosition();
  vector<pair <int, int> > listPiecesPosition(int** board);

  // What doesn't work
  vector<pair <int, int> > listPiecesPosition(int** board = this->board);
```

Game.cpp :

```
//Here I need to write more or less two times the same function, how can I do it only once ?

   vector<pair <int, int> > Game::listPiecesPosition() {
vector<pair <int, int> > listPiecesPosition;
for (int i=0; i < getSize(); i++)
  for (int j=0; j < getSize(); j++)
    if (getBoard()[i][j] == nextPlayer.getColor()) // Here I don't use the parameter
      listPiecesPosition.push_back(make_pair(i,j));
return listPiecesPosition;
  }

  vector<pair <int, int> > Game::listPiecesPosition(int** board) {
    vector<pair <int, int> > listPiecesPosition;
    for (int i=0; i < getSize(); i++)
      for (int j=0; j < getSize(); j++)
        if (board[i][j] == nextPlayer.getColor()) // Here I use the parameter
          listPiecesPosition.push_back(make_pair(i,j));
    return listPiecesPosition;
  }
```

Thanks for you help !

Comment: Default arguments must be compile-time resolvable. The value of `this` is only known at runtime.

Comment: @Danvdb  What is this in the return statement return listPiecesPosition;?

Comment: @Cameron: [That is not true](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc39783cabf27d22); this is just a scoping issue.

Comment: @Lightness: Huh, I stand corrected. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` can be used only inside the body of a non-static member function. Hence, your use of `this->board` as the default value of the input is not correct.

I suggest creating an overload to get around the problem.

```
class Game {
 private :
  int** board;

  vector<pair <int, int> > listPiecesPosition(int** board);
  vector<pair <int, int> > listPiecesPosition()
  {
     return listPiecesPosition(this->board);
  }
```

**PS** `this` can appear outside the body of a member function in limited contexts. This is not one of those situations.

**Update, in response to OP's comment**

Change

```
vector<pair <int, int> > Game::listPiecesPosition() {
   vector<pair <int, int> > listPiecesPosition;
   for (int i=0; i < getSize(); i++)
      for (int j=0; j < getSize(); j++)
         if (getBoard()[i][j] == nextPlayer.getColor()) // Here I don't use the parameter
            listPiecesPosition.push_back(make_pair(i,j));
   return listPiecesPosition;
}
```

to

```
vector<pair <int, int> > Game::listPiecesPosition() {
   return listPiecesPosition(this->board);
}
```

By doing this, you avoid duplication of code that implements the main logic of the functions.

Comment: The matter is that my function listPiecesPosition is very long and I don't want to copy two times the same code. Is it possible to do something like that :

    class Game {
    private :
    int** board;
    vector<pair <int, int> > listPiecesPosition(int** boardArgument = board);
    vector<pair <int, int> > listPiecesPosition(int** boardArgument)
    {
        return listPiecesPosition(boardArgument);
    }

Or I don't have any other choice that to overload my function ?

Comment: @Danvdb, you don't need to. The implementation of the second function is exactly what I posted in my answer.

Comment: The problem is that I don't want to use always the this->board inside my function. Sometimes the argument is a pointer to a an other board so inside the function I need to use board and not this->board

Comment: @Danvdb, that's why there are two overloaded functions. If you call `listPiecesPosition` with another board, the first overload will be called. If you cal it with no arguments, the second overload will be called. If this does not make sense, it's time to refresh your knowledge of C++ and overloaded functions.

Comment: I understand but with two overloaded functions, I need to more or less copy paste two times the same function no ?

Comment: @Danvdb, no. The code I posted for the second overload is all you need to implement it.

Comment: @Danvdb: Perhaps you did not spot that one overload invokes the other one.

Comment: `this` can appear outside the body of a member function in limited contexts. §5 [expr]

Comment: @remyabel, I didn't want to get into those details in this answer. Maybe I should add a "PS".

Comment: @RSahu : I edited my code above, can you show me what to do because I think I understand overloading but inside one function I need to use : this->board and in an other one I need to use juste boardArgument. But with your example I have the impression that because of the line : return ...this->board, it's always this->board that is used.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Thank you ! I understand much better now but the line : return listPiecesPosition->board; should be return listPiecesPosition(this->board) or it's the same ?